# impact of matrix storage method on cache miss penalty

Tags: c, caching, multidimensional-array

I'm tasked to implement a matrix-vector-multiplication using both a rows-first and a columns-first approach, when the matrix is stored row-major. Of course I expected lots of cache misses when the inner of a nested loop iterates over matrix rows and not columns. I wanted to know if and how the storage method of the matrix effects the cache miss penalty.

I reduced the following examples to the worst case computations, so multiplying a row-major matrix and a vector with a column-major algorithm. The row-major-matrix with row-major-algorithm does not show much of a difference between the storage methods.

The first approach uses an array of pointers to arrays to store a matrix in row-major order. The second approach uses a 1d array and linear index calculations.

#### Code

see https://godbolt.org/z/zqKs4vvxE

as requested in the comments

```
#include <stddef.h>  // for size_t
#include <stdio.h>   // for printf
#include <stdlib.h>  // for malloc and rand
#include <string.h>  // for memset
#include <time.h>    // for clock

#define NRUNS 10

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

float** create_random_matrix_aop(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) {
  float** matrix = malloc(n_rows * sizeof(*matrix));
  for (size_t i_row = 0; i_row < n_rows; ++i_row) {
    matrix[i_row] = malloc(n_cols * sizeof(*matrix[0]));
    for (size_t i_col = 0; i_col < n_cols; ++i_col) {
      matrix[i_row][i_col] = (float)rand();
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}

void matmul_col_major_2d(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols, float** matrix,
                         float* vector, float* result) {
  memset(result, 0, n_rows * sizeof(*result));
  for (size_t i_col = 0; i_col < n_cols; ++i_col) {
    for (size_t i_row = 0; i_row < n_rows; ++i_row) {
      result[i_row] += matrix[i_row][i_col] * vector[i_col];
    }
  }
}

void free_matrix(float** matrix, size_t n_rows) {
  for (size_t i_row = 0; i_row < n_rows; ++i_row) {
    free(matrix[i_row]);
  }
  free(matrix);
}

void array_of_pointers(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) {
  float** matrix = create_random_matrix_aop(n_rows, n_cols);
  float* vector = matrix[0];  // it's random values anyway
  float* result = malloc(n_rows * sizeof(result[0]));

  clock_t start;
  clock_t finish;
  clock_t elapsed;
  clock_t mean_elapsed;

  mean_elapsed = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < NRUNS; ++i) {
    start = clock();
    matmul_col_major_2d(n_rows, n_cols, matrix, vector, result);
    finish = clock();
    elapsed = finish - start;
    mean_elapsed += elapsed;
  }
  mean_elapsed /= NRUNS;
  printf("array_of_pointers: %16lu us ",
         mean_elapsed * 1000000ul / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  free_matrix(matrix, n_rows);
  free(result);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

float* create_random_matrix_1d(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) {
  size_t n_values = n_rows * n_cols;
  float* matrix = malloc(n_values * sizeof(*matrix));
  for (size_t i_value = 0; i_value < n_values; ++i_value) {
    matrix[i_value] = (float)rand();
  }
  return matrix;
}

void matmul_col_major_1d(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols, float* matrix,
                         float* vector, float* result) {
  memset(result, 0, n_rows * sizeof(*result));
  for (size_t i_col = 0; i_col < n_cols; ++i_col) {
    for (size_t i_row = 0; i_row < n_rows; ++i_row) {
      size_t i_lin = i_row * n_cols + i_col;
      result[i_row] += matrix[i_lin] * vector[i_col];
    }
  }
}

void linear_array(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) {
  float* matrix = create_random_matrix_1d(n_rows, n_cols);
  float* vector = matrix;  // it's random values anyway
  float* result = malloc(n_rows * sizeof(result[0]));

  clock_t start;
  clock_t finish;
  clock_t elapsed;
  clock_t mean_elapsed;

  mean_elapsed = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < NRUNS; ++i) {
    start = clock();
    matmul_col_major_1d(n_rows, n_cols, matrix, vector, result);
    finish = clock();
    elapsed = finish - start;
    mean_elapsed += elapsed;
  }
  mean_elapsed /= NRUNS;
  printf("linear_array: %16lu us ", mean_elapsed * 1000000ul / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  free(matrix);
  free(result);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
  size_t n_rows = 64;
  while (n_rows <= 8192) {
    size_t n_cols = n_rows;
    printf("matrix %4lu x %4lu ", n_rows, n_cols);
    linear_array(n_rows, n_cols);
    array_of_pointers(n_rows, n_cols);
    printf("\n");
    n_rows <<= 1;
  }
}
```

#### Results

The output on my machine (13th Gen Intel i7-1360P (16) @ 5.000GHz) with gcc 13.2.1 and `-O2` is:

```
matrix   64 x   64 linear_array:                2 us array_of_pointers:                2 us 
matrix  128 x  128 linear_array:               12 us array_of_pointers:               10 us 
matrix  256 x  256 linear_array:               58 us array_of_pointers:               52 us 
matrix  512 x  512 linear_array:              374 us array_of_pointers:              172 us 
matrix 1024 x 1024 linear_array:             2927 us array_of_pointers:              953 us 
matrix 2048 x 2048 linear_array:            19790 us array_of_pointers:             5331 us 
matrix 4096 x 4096 linear_array:           221155 us array_of_pointers:            54365 us 
matrix 8192 x 8192 linear_array:           974931 us array_of_pointers:           306641 us
```

Most of the posts and articles I found said that one continuous block of memory should have advantages over the array of pointers. But in this (bad) case the performance of the 1d array is way worse.

Please help me understand why that is.

Comment: You can always switch the loops, to loop over column-row instead of row-column. Though, if you allow mixing row-major and column-major in expressions, one of the matrices will always have bad access patterns no matter what you do.

Comment: I want to explicitly know about the penalty in the mixed case. Both matrices are row major only differently stored in memory, one contiguous, one spread across multiple heap arrays

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre] in the question, not only as a link to an external site.

Comment: With large matrices or images the trick is to avoid column major operations since almost everything is a cache miss once you get large enough. If it is necessary to do  an operation that would be column major then transpose the array first with a cache aware matrix transpose routine. This arises in 2D and higher dimension FFTs for example. An alternative in this instance is to sum the dot product into an array of length N so as to keep the memory access sequential and local. I'm surprised that array of pointers won here. Worth a factor of three when N>256 - not insignificant.

Comment: I know that this access pattern is bad (I explicitly made it so), but I'm as surprised as you that the array of pointers had a better runtime in this case than the 1d array. I'd like to understand why.

Comment: @j-hap I think I like the answer already given. But you can check if that is right by allocating a single huge array and then setting pointers into it. Then you will have the same linear  contiguous 1D bulk array as before but can feed it into the routine expecting N pointers. I vaguely recall something similar happening with power of 2 FFTs as CPU caches became ever smarter and multilevel. What it shows is that the experiment is always worth doing.

Comment: @j-hap another thought is try 3^N, 5^N and 10^N lengths which should result in very different cache locations for each start of a row in the linear array.

Comment: nice catch @MartinBrown, for a power of 3: I get `matrix 6561 x 6561: linear_array:            63991 us, array_of_pointers: 178967 us`, power of 5: `matrix 3125 x 3125: linear_array: 13943 us, array_of_pointers: 30136 us` and power of 10: `matrix 10000 x 10000: linear_array: 98230 us, array_of_pointers: 483493 us`

Comment: regarding the "fake" array of pointers pointing into a linear chunk: it shows the same behavior as the linear array (a bit worse, probably because of additional indirection), which means that in the true array-of-pointers case the rows are placed more cache friendly, that's amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of cache misses in the array of pointers is a function of where `malloc` allocates each row. If they happen to be at diverse offsets relative to the cache geometry, traversing a column of them may cause fewer conflicts than traversing elements of a column in an actual array where all those elements map to the same few cache sets.

Comment: as @MartinBrown pointed out, the effect can be inverted when the rows aren´t a power of 2 big, which I think proves your point.